# author.php not listing co-author's posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the plugin Co-Authors Plus to display multiple authors per post. It works fine, but... How can I get the co-authors' posts listed on author.php for a custom post type? At the moment, a post with several co-authors appear listed only in the first author's author profile, but not in their co-authors' profiles as it should.

Here's my code in author.php

```
<?php
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($coauthor));
$args = array(
'author' => $author,
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'bookshelf',
'post_status' => 'publish',
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<div class="masonry-item"><h2>Bookshelf</h2>';
echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$the_query->the_post();
echo '<li>';
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul></div>';
} else {
// no posts found
}

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: 'author' => $author, The $author is not define

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that?

Comment: in your code $args = array(
'author' => $author,
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'bookshelf',
'post_status' => 'publish',
); The variable $author is not define above

Comment: Sorry, the variable is defined at the top of author.php:  `<?php

 global $coauthors_plus;
 if (isset($coauthors_plus)) {
  $curauth = $coauthors_plus->get_coauthor_by( 'user_nicename', $author_name );
 } else {
      if(isset($_GET['author_name'])) :
        $curauth = get_userdatabylogin($author_name);
        else :
        $curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));
      endif;
 }

  ?>`  The problem is not that it doesn't list the author's posts, it is that it only lists the posts for which the author is the main author, not the co-author.